# Is overlapping of two coherent EM wave a type of interference?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Suppose we overlap two coherent EM waves,Is this a type of interference.this may be a possibility because they all the necessary condition for interference.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's meant by interference.

Comment: Is it interference when they both are travelling in the same direction as they overlap?

Comment: Yes. For example, this is what happens in a Michelson interferometer.

Comment: @Anns They can’t interfere with each other until they get to a screen where they can form an interference pattern.